# how to make forest with different types of trees

Tags: particles

I want to create a forest. I have already created a few types of trees and now I want them to "grow" out of a plane. I would use a particle system, but I have a few issues: firstly, the trees can't decide whether to stand or lie, I tried to change this using the duplicate object settings, but it was changing randomly without being afected by the settings. Secondly, I could not think of any way, how to make the two different trees not overlap each other (although I found here how to do that with only one type) and lastly, for some reason when I added the second particle system it generated only one tree instead of 1000 which is defalut. 
I am not familiar with using python with blender. the trees are realy simple and low poly models, without any sofisticated details.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39192/599

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/which-particle-system-is-best-for-trees-in-a-forest and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mask system's density and Render Groups

To avoid interaction between two particle system you should somehow mask their density in a complementary way, so where one is the other isn't.

---

Let's start from creating a simple forest with two type of trees and only one particle system:

After modeling the tree types, you should assigning your sample trees objects to a group (select and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Then add to your surface a particle system with these two characteristics:

- Hair particles initial orientation on **Global Z** with **random phase** as well described in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39192/making-hair-go-straight-up-instead-of-following-the-shape) to get trees pointin straight up and with some random rotation around the Z axis
- Render option set to **Group** (pointing to the previously created group)
  with **Rotation** (rotate your object towart the X axis as in the picture) and **Pick random**

[image]

The last mentioned option will pick a random object from the target group, resulting in an assorted forest.

To get full control, you can use the **Count** option instead which would let you choose in wich proportion each tree type is present in the forest

[image]

Above you can see a fores made by 90% of pines and 10% of Betullae.

---

Now add a second particle system, this time made by 20% Pines and 80% Betullaes:

[image]

Go to weight paint, create a new vertex group layers and start paining red the places where the Pines (90%) will be. Then duplicate the vertex group (Copy vertex grup from the menue), **Invert** the weight, paint some 0 weight areas (where you don't want anty tree) and rename the vertex group to Pines 20%.

[image]

[image]

Assign to each particle system the appropriate vertex weight group and you'll have a two-tree-type forest:

[image]

Apart from vertex weight, you can mask the two particles system even with textures, or splitting the surface in many different objects... it depends on what your project's workflow is.

---

To avoid intersection between particles you should keep an eye on [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36892/how-to-use-emitter-for-generating-thick-forest-so-that-trees-would-not-intersect) related question. Sadly there is not a exaustive answer yet.