# Hierarchical particle system for a forest

Tags: mesh, particles, collections

I have two tree objects, each consisting of a trunk, and a particle system with leaves:
[image: trees]

I would like to instance them as a forest on a mountain (a separate object). When adding a particle system there, none of the options seem to cover my use case:

1. When I select `Render As > Object`, and choose `Ahorn tree`, only the trunk (and not the child `leafs.001` are rendered.
2. When I choose `Collection` and choose a collection that contains both trees, I get each object (two trunks, two leafs with particle systems, and leaves) separately.
3. When I choose `Collection` and choose a collection that contains only one tree, and then `Whole collection`:
   [image: whole collection]

I still don't see leaves, and the trunks are placed all over the place:
[image: whole collection]

Is there an easy way to make a hierarchical particle system? I don't want to make leaf instances real, as this will crash blender due to resource usage. I suspect I'd see the same with the Particle Instance modifier.

I saw [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/which-particle-system-is-best-for-trees-in-a-forest) about a particle system for a forest, but it doesn't consider the problem of the tree using a particle system itself.

Comment: i tried my best to get this work with geonodes, but...for me...it looks like a bug. Because as soon as i just add a material, the particles were....gone. check this out: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJWeT.gif maybe this is worth a bug report...

Comment: but as solution for you i would go with geonodes (and won't work with particles) because geonodes are (at least with the latest versions) great and forests should be done with that (just my opinion) and you will find tutorials about building forest/trees on yt (e.g. erindale...)

Comment: Thanks, Chris! I managed to make it work with geonodes, not sure why it doesn't work for you :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with the use of geometry nodes, like this:
[image: geonodes]